# Parse XML document to Ruby collection using XSD for type hinting

Tags: ruby, xsd, xml-parsing, nokogiri, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to fetch an XML document from a 3rd party. HTTParty uses MultiXML under the hood, which uses Nokogiri by default to parse the returned document to a collection of Ruby objects. Some of the nodes in the XML document are supposed to be arrays of "1 or more" or "0 or more" elements (aka sequences), but when they contain only a single element they are returned as just the value of the parent element, not as a single item in an array. The party hosting these XML files also provides an XSD for the document that includes information about which nodes are supposed to be sequences. I understand Nokogiri has a Schema utility for validating a document against an XSD, but is there a way to use the schema to provide type hinting to the document parser so these array nodes are properly represented in the returned Ruby collection?

For example, given the following abridged XML document:

```
xml_doc = <<EOT
<Get_Workers_Response>
  <Response_Data>
    <Worker>
      <Personal_Data>
        <Contact_Data>
          <Address_Data>
            <Address_Line_Data>123 A Street</Address_Line_Data>
          </Address_Data>
        </Contact_Data>
      </Personal_Data>
    </Worker>
  </Response_Data>
</Get_Workers_Response>
EOT
```

The Nokogiri parser outputs:

```
MultiXml.parser # => MultiXml::Parsers::Nokogiri
pp MultiXml.parse xml_doc
{"Get_Workers_Response"=>
  {"Response_Data"=>
    {"Worker"=>
      {"Personal_Data"=>
        {"Contact_Data"=>
          {"Address_Data"=>{"Address_Line_Data"=>"123 A Street"}}}}}}}
```

When based on the schema it should be:

```
{"Get_Workers_Response"=>
  {"Response_Data"=>
    {"Worker"=> # An array of worker data
      [{"Personal_Data"=>
         {"Contact_Data"=> # An array of Address line data
           {"Address_Data"=>{"Address_Line_Data"=>["123 A Street"]}}}}]}}}
```

I'm not stuck with MultiXML/Nokogiri, so if there's a better parser to use for this situation I'm up for giving it a try.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". You're giving us data, but not showing us how you're getting Nokogiri's output, which is essential to the question. MultiXML allows the use of multiple different XML parsers. Nokogiri won't return a Hash so something else is processing the data; Possibly MultiXML, or it's using Ox, which does return a Hash. Processing using Nokogiri by itself is easy and I wouldn't bother with anything else but YMMV.

Comment: I've updated the example to the exact ruby I was using to test. MultiXML is indeed using Nokogiri as the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't asked well, but it sounds like you might not be parsing the data correctly. It is possible to always get the content of a single or multiple nodes as an array, so you only have to worry about processing arrays:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<Get_Workers_Response>
  <Address_Line_Data>123 A Street</Address_Line_Data>
</Get_Workers_Response>
</xml>
EOT

ald = doc.search('Address_Line_Data').map(&:text) # => ["123 A Street"]
```

`ald` is an array of text at this point.

If there are two records, assuming they look like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<Get_Workers_Response>
  <Address_Line_Data>123 A Street</Address_Line_Data>
  <Address_Line_Data>456 A Street</Address_Line_Data>
</Get_Workers_Response>
</xml>
EOT

ald = doc.search('Address_Line_Data').map(&:text) # => ["123 A Street", "456 A Street"]
```

`ald` is still an array of strings.